# I am not able to fetch data from from the Array using ngFor -Not sure what is going wrong

Tags: angular2-services

I know it seems a very simple issue but i got stuck at the point and need some help .Trying to create a website using angular 2 --i have the data which i can see in console log but when i am trying to fetch over HTML Page -Nothing is coming.

This is my users.component.html page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

users:any;

  constructor(private firebaseservice:FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseservice.getusers().subscribe(users=>{
      this.users=users;
      console.log(users);

    });
  }

}
```

[Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFzzY.png)

This is my users.component.html Page

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users">
    {{user.title}}
  </li>
  </ul>
```

[Could not see any Data in Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP3a2.png)

Comment: Does `user` has a `title` property? I can't see it on provided images

Comment: yes it has :Kdl_wRRkn7nJxgz4B54
:
bedrooms
:
15
city
:
"San Francisco"
image
:
"mansion1.jpg"
owner
:
"Bruce Springstien"
path
:
"/img/mansion1.jpg"
price
:
"10m"
title
:
"15 Bedroom Mansion"
type
:
"Estate"

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to make your `users:any;` public, like this: `public users: any;`

Comment: did the change,still same problem

Comment: Can you show `ul` and `li` elements in the inspector?

Comment: No, I mean HTML element's inspector, F12 in Chrome to open it.

Comment: my service where getuser() method is export class FirebaseService {

users:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(private af:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getusers()
  {

    this.users=this.af.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<Users[]>
    return this.users;
    
  }

  

}
interface Users{

$key?:string;
title?:string;
type?:string;
image?:string;
city?:string;
owner?:string;
bedrooms?:string;
path?:string;
price?:string; 
  }

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCVXRMZUJmci1PYVU

Comment: On your screenshot "console" tab is selected, select "elements" tab and find `li` elements.

Comment: Elemtents link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCOWNoSGFUNkFPdEU

Comment: Hm, it's a little strange. Sorry, I can't find the issue, may be someone else will help you...

Comment: Np @CommercialSuicide thnks for your help.If you click anything let me know

Comment: Sure, I will...

Comment: Appreciate if someone else  can help me on this

Comment: @jonrsharpe  can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have an array which contains one object with your results. ng-for requires iterable data (Array) which is not the case in your result.

You should go through your objects and push every single object in your users array. You can use for...in to achieve this

```
var result = {};
result.a = {name: 'test'};
result.b = {name: 'test2'};

var users = [];

for (let user in result) {
  users.push(result[user]);
}
```

Then your users array should be iterable.

In your code this should be like:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseservice.getusers().subscribe(users=>{
      for (let user in users) {
          this.users.push(users[user]);
      }
    });
```